# Selecting API Response JSON Field in Cypress Resulted as Undefined

Tags: cypress, automation-testing

I have a problem regarding Cypress response evaluation. I'm intercepting a request and trying to get a field which is returned as "Undefined". Here is the structure of the response directly fetched from browser:

```
[{"hyperparams": {"param1": 50, "param2": 0.1}, "eval_score": 0.41176470588235303}]
```

The way that I try to get "eval_score" is follows:

```
cy.wait("@trial").then(({ response }) => {
          expect(response.body[0]["eval_score"]).within(0, 5);
        });
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `response.body[0]` return the correct object? Does that object need to be JSON-ified?

Comment: @agoff actually I tried to log the 'response.body[0]' and on output panel it prints "[". This is super strange.

Comment: Do you have more success with `response.body`? It may be easier to use `cy.log`, if you're currently using `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[` you are seeing when logging `response.body[0]` is indicative you have not deserialised the response. It's a string containing JSON and not the object itself, so `0` is accessing the first character of a string (strings behave like this with array accessors in JS).

Try

```
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[0]["eval_score"]).within(0, 5);
```